# Write variating numbers after specific text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a standardized text with different information. I would like Excel to automatically extract that information. The text can be:

Bietet (schriftlich): KP 10.700.000 EUR / Maklerhonorar nicht geklärt

I would like Excel to extract the "schriftlich", "10.700.000" and "nicht geklärt"
It would always stand like this, and the data I want extracted can vary.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

For *schriftlich* cell B5:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1)
```

For *10.700.000* cell B6:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)+1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1)-1)
```

For *nicht geklärt* cell B7:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND("/",A1)+2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to make some changes in my reporting document to get this implemented, but they work like a charm now. I have a problem on the last one "nicht geklärt". There will often be some text after this, which I just cut out in my example, because it was unimportant. All this text is also displayed, and I would of course like it to stop. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: You'd better provide detail sample

Comment: The thing is, that the data can variate a lot. It can be a small text like a date, but it can also be a long description. I like your solution for _schriftlich_ because no matter what, it always finds whatever is in the clams. If something is different with the price, like there is an "Update:" in front, it doesn't take the price. I solved this by using the substitute formula.
`=substitute(substitute(substitute(substitute(A1,"KP ","KP [")," EUR","] EUR"),"Maklerhonorar ","Maklerhonorar {")," (Stand","} (Stand")`
This also solved my other problem. Thank you very much for your help